# How to combine rows in a dataframe based on identical value in multiple columns

Tags: r

The title says it all, I have a  large dataset that consists of factory and latitude and longitude, and among others. some of the factories I find have identical lat long although their name slightly different. How can I merge rows of factories that have the same lat-long in R?

| mill | latitude | longitude | ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a. | 12.34. | 7.86. | NA |
| A. | 12.34. | 7.86. | 4 |
| b | 47.56. | 27.07. | 5. |

The output I am looking for is:

| mill | latitude | longitude | ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a. | 12.34. | 7.86. | 4. |
| b. | 47.56. | 27.07. | 5 |

Answer (score 1):

We can use `distinct`

```
library(dplyr)
distinct(df1, latitude, longitude, .keep_all = TRUE)
#    mill latitude longitude
#1   a.   12.34.     7.86.
#2   b.   47.56.    27.07.
```

With the updated question, an option is to do an `arrange` first as `distinct` takes the `first` unique row

```
df1 %>%
   arrange(latitude, longitude, is.na(ID)) %>%
   distinct(latitude, longitude, .keep_all = TRUE)
```

Comment: Hi @akrun, I have updated my question.

Comment: @FH I updated the post.  If the dupe tag doesn't solve your problem, can you please flag it